# How to add horizontal scrollbar for Expanded rows in Power BI Matrix?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have turned off the stepped layout for the matrix & added more fields to the row section. But I can't Horizontally scroll through the expanded rows section. It's like frozen. Is there any way to scroll that?
[image]